# Push notifications, testing on production enviroment problems after update to xcode 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, ios9, xcode7

I have a published app in the app store that uses push notifications. Everything works correctly.

So far, to test, what I did was load the app on my devices to test in a sandbox environment and create an ad hoc distribution to test it in a production environment.

But after upgrading to Xcode 7.0.1 and iOS 9 I'm having serious problems to test the app. In the sandbox environment everything works as before, but when I generate ad hoc distribution, the token is generated by the development environment.

I am also having problems since the dialogue to your acceptance or not receive notifications does not appear even if you delete the app and reinstall it.

Someone with the same problem after updating xcode? Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

EDITED: Im getting the following error: A error code of 8 indicates that the device token is invalid. This could be for a number of reasons - are you using the correct environment? i.e. Production vs. Sandbox

Comment: have you checked your EDIT SCHEME setting?

Comment: No, what can I check there?

Comment: check this URL : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeProfile.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH3-SW1.   select ARCHIVE and set ADHOC.

Comment: Inside Profile, in build configuration I have Release. Them on the xcode menu I choose Product-->Archive And them Ad hoc deployment. Is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check for apns certificate do you use on server side for testing (Prod/Dev).

Try to save for development deployment 
[image]

Comment: The certificates on server side are ok. If I load the ipa generated by xcode 6.4 all works ok. The problem comes when I generated the package for Ad Hoc distribution with xcode 7.0.1 (Second option).

Comment: via xCode 6.4 your generate ipa as Ad Hoc distribution?

Comment: For test purpose your should use development provision and generate ipa (see image above). and on server side use development apns certificate

Comment: Yes, on xCode 6.4 I generated as Ad Hoc distribution to test on production with production certificates. And works until now.

Comment: If I test on development environment, with development certificates on the server all works ok.

Comment: The problem comes when i want to test on production, the AD Hoc package is generating a development token, no a production token, so the APNS service is throwing an error.

Comment: This is the error: A error code of 8 indicates that the device token is invalid. This could be for a number of reasons - are you using the correct environment? i.e. Production vs. Sandbox

Comment: I think you can't use production APNS for test purposes

Comment: You can, generating Ad Hoc package and installing from itunes.